# All pages showing "Access Denied" if not logged in

Tags: 7, users

I am on MAMP, able to login and try to figure things out. (First time developing in Drupal). I am using Drupal 7, with Project Kickstart distribution. https://drupal.org/project/project_kickstart

This is meant to be a public site in the end - any idea what I should be checking to see why anonymous user cannot view content? I checked `node_access` and there is an entry for GID 0. There is also a user 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are logged in as admin, go to /admin/people/permissions and make sure that anonymous users are given *View published content* permissions.

If you are new to Drupal, you should probably stay away from the database tables for now.

Comment: Thanks. Was a difficult thing to "search" for, for some reason. Many things talked about the `node_access`. And, new to Drupal, not to databases ;)

Comment: Glad to have helped. I was not mentioning the databases to belittle your abilities. Drupal databases are not intuitive. Until you understand how the system utilizes the tables, it is better to work down through the interface, through the php, and then into the storage in your learning curve. I have been designing databases for years, and I can remember some really bad mistakes I made when I was learning to use Drupal :-) Good Luck.